# Default export in ES6 - array of functions. How it works?

Tags: ecmascript-6

Would you kindly explain how the import marked in red can work? For me, it simply does not. (they are using it in [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/ba60700aeef339e0c0ce35bfc242aea7fb0477e9/app/containers/HomePage/sagas.js) template)
Please excuse me, I am not an experienced JS developer.

The export is done as a default array of functions (as below).

```
// Bootstrap sagas
export default [
  githubData,
];
```

The import is done in standard way in a [test file](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/ba60700aeef339e0c0ce35bfc242aea7fb0477e9/app/containers/HomePage/tests/sagas.test.js) as below.

```
import { githubData } from '../sagas';
```

My point is, if the githubData was exported as "export function* githubData" I think there would be no problem. However I am not sure how importing member of default array of functions can work in this way. Maybe I have incompatible version of babel, node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the githubData was exported as `export function* githubData` i think there would be no problem

Well, there is no problem because that's [exactly how it *is* exported](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/ba60700aeef339e0c0ce35bfc242aea7fb0477e9/app/containers/HomePage/sagas.js#L43). Being also a part of the default-exported value doesn't stop it from working.